# Villani's Lazy Gas experiment: Meaning of intermediate distribution having maximum entropy?

Tags: probability-distributions, physics, statistical-inference, entropy, optimal-transport

Taken from Villani's 2006 book on optimal transport to describe the figure that follows:

> The Lazy Gas experiment: Take a perfect gas in which particles do not interact, and ask him to move from a certain prescribed density field at time t = 0, to another prescribed density field at time t = 1. Since the gas is lazy, he will find a way to do so by spending a minimal amount of work (least action path). Measure the entropy of the gas at each time,
> and check that it always lie above the line joining the final and initial entropies. If such is the case, then we know that we live in a nonnegatively curved space (see Figure 16.2).

[image]

The "gas" described is essentially a variable whose sample observations form, or can be represented as, a probability distribution or density so that Boltzmann's entropy translates to Shannon entropy since they are twin concepts designed for their respective fields.

### Question

Is there some significance or meaning in, and reason why, the intermediate state $\left(t=\frac{1}{2}\right)$ of a gas or distribution has higher entropy than its initial (source) and final (target) states (densities)? The chapters ends there, but where is this experiment even going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim follows immediately from a deep result of von Renesse and Sturm (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.20060) which tells that for any smooth and connected Riemannian manifold and $K>0$ the following statements are equivalent:

1. Ricci curvature is bounded from below by $K$, i.e.
   $\operatorname{Ric}(M)\ge K$
2. the entropy $H:=-S$ is displacement $K$-convex, i.e. \begin{equation} H(\mu_{t})\le (1-t)H(\mu_{0})+tH(\mu_{1})-\frac{K}{2}t(1-t)d_{W}^{2}(\mu_{0},\mu_{1}), \end{equation} with $d_{W}$ being the Wasserstein-2-distance.

Comment: is the Lazy Gas trajectory saying that an intermediate state along the geodesic interpolation path between the source and target states/distributions is more desirable than the target itself because it has higher entropy due to the convexity of that path (which actually looks concave to me in the figure)?

Comment: The statement is more about geometry. Think of how a liquid or gas or whatever would typically evolve from one to another configuration on a sphere on one hand and one hyperboloid on the other hand. Due to the positive curvature of the sphere the gas will have a tendency to spread out, and the opposite on a hyperboloid. This spreading out corresponds to an increase/decrease of entropy.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this in the situation that the gas is replaced with a probability distribution, plus the change in dispersion behavior that might come with this replacement. Can the question in my previous comment be answered in that light, which I've provided my own feeling as to what the answer is within the same comment from an optimization perspective (interrupted migration along the interpolation path) rather than giving a purely geometric observation of what one *sees*

Comment: I'm no physicist at all. Whenever I write gas or liquid, I actually mean some time-evolving family of probability measures.

Comment: would you say that the figure they provide is concave or convex

Comment: Your $S$, which is my $-H$ is concave.

Comment: With the increase in entropy due to distribution $\mu$ having a tendency to spread out/diffuse mid-way, is this state more desirable than the target $\mu_1$ itself?